# Algorithm to compute a 3D voronoi diagram for a cube

Tags: voronoi

I want to compute a 3D voronoi diagram for a cube. Which algorithms can I use to compute it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as suggested when you signed up today, to get a better idea of what types of questions you can ask. This question is off-topic: It's unclear & very broad.

Comment: Hello. I reduced your question assuming you actualy ask for an algorithm (library requests and general programming help are off topic here) and thus removed the python tag and reduced your question to ask for algorithms to compute 3D voronoi diagrams.